# Multiple ring buffer in ArcMap gives Update parameters execution error

Tags: arcgis-desktop, arcmap, buffer

My issue is with multiple ring buffer in ArcGIS Desktop 10.8.1. I'm dealing with GIS1 workbook Tutorial 9-3. Every time trying to enter distances I get this error message telling me:

> Update parameters execution error`

What should I do?

Comment: What parameter values are you using?

Answer (score 1):

I remember this error was existing in ArcMap 10.0, and the error was caused by a few regional language preferences set for the machines. Languages like "French, Swedish, and Czech", showed this particular behaviour.

So, if you are using any regional language try to set the machine's language to US Region, and check if the issue is reproducible.

Comment: Thanks a lot it might be the case. Cause I'm from Israel and the language is Hebrew. May I point that the problem doesn't appear in the buffer tool, but does appear too with the Grouping Analysis tool.

Comment: Is the issue with the Buffer tool or the grouping analysis tool? In the original question you have mentioned the buffer tool, so can you please reconfirm.